# Integrating with built-in SMS application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms

I want to make use of sms in my iPhone application. I realized that its impossible to integrate SMS module, rather we can just switch over to iPhone's SMS application by passing number.

I had tried the following but I am still not able to open inbuilt SMS application.

```
NSString *no = @"9904143445";
NSString *sms = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"smsto:%@",no];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sms]];
```

Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you accept someone's answer?

Answer (score 7):

Your URL protocol is wrong: "smsto" should be just "sms"

Comment: And don't forget; the SMS isn't working in the Simulator, only in your device.

Answer (score 4):

We have used sms:+1254545454 from our web app [built specially for iPhone] and it invokes the in-built SMS application absolutely fine.